# Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list' error in R random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

[image: My data]I am using the airbnb dataset. After cleaning it, I tried to apply a random forest (I did a tree and a pruned tree and they worked). I don't have a lot of experience but here is my code :

```
split_index <- createDataPartition(airbnbcleanedfinal$logprice, p = 0.8, list = F)

#Use index to split data
training<-training <- airbnbcleanedfinal[split_index,]
training1 <- airbnbcleanedfinal[sample(nrow(airbnbcleanedfinal),100000,replace=TRUE),]
features_test <- airbnbcleanedfinal[-split_index, !(colnames(airbnbcleanedfinal) %in% c('logprice'))]
target_test <- airbnbcleanedfinal[-split_index, 'logprice']

library(randomForest)


rf_train <- randomForest(logprice ~ ., data = airbnbcleanedfinal,
                         subset=training,
                         mtry = 5)
```

But I always get the same error message :

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

I also tried to delete subset=training and put directly data=training but it makes R run forever. I also tried using training1 that I created for that purpose but still got the same error message.

I tried unlist(training) but it did not work. My data is huge (85k-15 variables) too, maybe that is the problem? How can I force training to be a list?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data you're using for ``randomForest()`` please?

Comment: I just added a picture of my data.

Comment: We'd really like to have a sample of your data that we can easily work with. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about reproducible examples.